# Managed to install Ubuntu alongside Windows7 with Gparted; now can't get back into Windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I hoped to make a dual-boot install of Ubuntu (from USB w/ Ubuntu 14.10-desktop-amd64.iso) next to Windows 7, but dual-boot option was not presented. I chose "something else", shrunk Windows, created an ext4 partition for Ubuntu (tried to create a swap partition, but all free space was "unuseable") and installed. I love Ubuntu! *but* now I can't boot into Windows. At startup there's no option to boot either, just straight to Ubuntu. AFAIK, I'm not supposed to have to go into BIOS at startup to do this, or am I wrong? Any and all ideas appreciated.

Thank you, 
realself

Comment: First run this: sudo update-grub But mode Windows 7 systems used all 4 primary partitions with BIOS and MBR partitioning. What partition did you delete to get Ubuntu to install. Most delete a vendor utilities. But if you deleted the 100MB Boot partition, Windows has no boot files.

Comment: I didn't delete a partition, I shrunk Windows from 300 Gb to 120 Gb, created a new partition. There were only 3 partitions evident: Windows, the Q:drive factory reset, and the few gigs from the Ubuntu install. I will run the grub update to see what's there, thanks.

Comment: @oldfred , Re Windows, it shows:

Found: memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found: memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found: Windows Recovery Environment (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found: Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda2

Comment: run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Does not the entry for sda2 work? That is saying that grub2's os-prober did see Windows boot files on sda2. If that does not work post link to the summary report from Boot-Repair. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair But Boot-Repair can only fix very minor Windows issues and you may need your Windows install disk or a Windows repair CD or flash drive to run the Windows repair console. And often after Windows fixes you have to reinstall grub to MBR. Boot-Repair then is an easy way to restore grub to MBR or you can manually do it from live installer.

Comment: @oldfred D'oh!! I'd been missing the Windows option under all the Ubuntu + memtest stuff, didn't notice till I restarted w/ Escape button. I'd always assumed it a strictly Ubuntu screen -I'd been expecting BIOS looking stuff. All's well now, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu, how to fix?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217904/unable-to-boot-into-windows-after-installing-ubuntu-how-to-fix)